# Как поместить список моделей в Cache хранилище (Memcached) Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Как поместить список моделей  в Cache хранилище (Memcached) Laravel.

Comment: что именно вы имеете в виду? метаданные у структуре таблиц и связей в кэш поместить, или какие-то загруженные из БД данные?

Comment: И зачем вам список моделей в мемкеше?